# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Filtering LINQ query with outer joins

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a requirement to query for records in CRM that *don't* have a related entity of a certain type. Normally, I would do this with an Left Outer Join, then filter for all the rows that have NULLs in the right-hand side.

For example:

```
var query = from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
            join aj in orgContext.CreateQuery<Account>()
                on c.ContactId equals aj.PrimaryContactId.Id
            into wonk
            from a in wonk.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where a.Name == null
            select new Contact
                   {
                       FirstName = c.FirstName,
                       LastName = c.LastName,
                   };
```

This should return me any Contats that are not the Primary Contact of an account. However, this query ends up returning **all** contacts...! When you look at the SQL that gets generated in SQL Profiler it comes out like this:

```
SELECT cnt.FirstName, cnt.LastName
FROM Contact as cnt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Account AS acct
        ON cnt.ContactId = acct.PrimaryContactId AND acct.Name is NULL
```

So, I get the Left Join OK, but the filter is *on* the `Join` clause, and not in a `WHERE` clause.and not as it should, like this:

```
SELECT cnt.FirstName, cnt.LastName
FROM Contact as cnt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Account AS acct
        ON cnt.ContactId = acct.PrimaryContactId
WHERE acct.Name is NULL
```

Clearly, the results from this query are very different! Is there a way to get the query on CRM to generate the correct SQL?

Is this a limitation of the underlying FetchXML request?

Comment: which table does "Name" column belong to?

Comment: @Hassan, Name is a field on the Account entity. I just chose a field that I thought should always have data for this example. In reality my query is not between built in entities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of CRM's LINQ and FetchXML implementations. This page from the SDK states outer joins are not supported:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx

And while I can't find an official document, there are a lot of results out there for people mentioning FetchXML does not support left outer joins, for example:

http://gtcrm.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/fetch-xml-reports-for-crm-2011-online/

Comment: It's odd the docs say that, because the outer join itself actually worked. The filtering of the results from the right hand side is the problem. Using raw FetchXML seems to have exatly the same problem.

Comment: Outer joins worked for me also, but I had other problems with trying to add a join to the query.

Comment: I upvoted the answer because it seems right, but it is also disappointing to find at the same time. My data access to CRM is becoming an awful mix of LINQ, QueryExpression and ADO.NET queries on the filtered views where the others just don't work. The ADO.NET queries are becoming more an more prevalent as QueryExpression for large queries becomes too disjointed and difficult to see the wood for the trees, while LINQ (CRM's version) seems to lackluster in terms of its capabilities :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
            where orgContext.CreateQuery<Account>().All(aj => c.ContactId != aj.PrimaryContactId.Id)                
            select new Contact
            {
                   FirstName = c.FirstName,
                   LastName = c.LastName,
            };
```

Comment: Hmmm, but I want to filter on a.Name, not c.Name?

Comment: @Hassan. Sorry, that really won't work - there are no Accounts with a Null name. The `a.Name == null` in my example query is trying to select the rows with no matching account.

Comment: @Mark. Check now. In cases where outer joins don't work, you can do something like this.

Comment: @Hassan. Nice idea, but sadly FetchXML in Dynamics CRM doesn't support subqueries either

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to update the entity (e.g. to process all the corresponding validation rules and workflow steps), you can write less-ugly and more efficient queries by hitting the SQL Server directly.

Per CRM's pattern, the views take care of most of the common joins for you. For instance, the `dbo.ContactBase` and `dbo.ContactExtensionBase` tables are already joined for you in the view `dbo.Contact`. The AccountName is already there (called AccountIdName for some bizarre reason, but at least it's there).