# Dynamics CRM 2011 Linq Left Outer Join

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get all records from an entity that do not join to another entity.

This is what I am trying to do in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * from table1 
LEFT join table2
ON table1.code = table2.code
WHERE table2.code IS NULL
```

It results in all table1 rows that did not join to table2.

I have it working with Linq when joining on one field, but I have contact records to join on firstname, dob, and number.

I have a "staging" entity that is imported to; a workflow processes the staging records and creates contacts if they are new.
The staging entity is pretty much a copy of the real entity.

```linq
var queryable = from staging in linq.mdo_staging_contactSet
                join contact in linq.ContactSet
                on staging.mdo_code equals contact.mdo_code
                into contactGroup
                from contact in contactGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                // all staging records are selected, even if I put a where clause here
                select new Contact 
                {
                    // import sequence number is set to null if the staging contact joined to the default contact, which has in id of null
                    ImportSequenceNumber = (contactContactId == null) ? new int?(subImportNo) : null,
                    /* other fields get populated */
                };
return queryable // This is all staging Contacts, the below expressions product only the new Contacts   
    .AsEnumerable() // Cannot use the below query on IQuerable
    .Where(contact => contact.ImportSequenceNumber != null); // ImportSequenceNumber is null for existing Contacts, and not null for new Contacts
```

Can I do the same thing using method syntax?

Can I do the above and join on multiple fields?

The alternatives I found were worse and involved using newRecords.Except(existingRecords), but with IEnumerables; is there a better way?

Comment: I was just looking into this myself. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6333207/685760) seems to indicate that it isn't possible with CRMs implementation of LINQ. See the [limitations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328328.aspx#limitations) section of the linked MSDN doco saying `You cannot perform outer joins`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing with method calls, but some tend to find it harder to read since there are some LAMBDA expressions in the middle. [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join) is an example that shows how the two are basically the same.

I've seen others ask this same questions and it boils down to choice by the developer. I personally like the LINQ approach since I also write a bunch of SQL and I can read the code easier.